# How to put all your photos on Android to Google Drive?

Tags: sync, photos, google-drive

I want an automatic solution for every picture I take to go to Google Drive once I have a WiFi connection. Once it's synced to Google Drive, I'll just copy it to my other drive. On iPhone, every photo I took go to iCloud automatically.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: There's [Google Photos Auto Backup](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6193313?hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

I used [Google Photos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos) now. That seems to be the solution I want.